# how to get character size?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Any help would be great, thank you in advance. Right now I'm hard coding each character size

```
such as A = 8px and B = 7px etc
```

and storing in a hash table

My current page have a menu with each category taken from a database

so the menu can change when needed

for example i could have 10 category in the menu section such as reviews, contact us and products.

The problem is the length of the menu section is 1000px in width

it would display correctly in some browser such as IE 7-10 and in chrome it would exceeding the length over flowing to the sides.

Depending on the browser it would a just the size of the character.

so each category would fit in the menu. Is their a method or some way to get the size of the a word so it would display on the major browsers correctly?

Thank you sorry about the wording and grammar English is not my first language.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst, from what I'm gathering the OP would like to measure all of the characters up front so that they can be used to determine the length of a string based on a specific font.

Comment: I'd suggest you to look at the CSS Units:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp and make your application use dynamic dimensions like percentage for width, and perhaps em for font size.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you'd have to declare the dictionary and store it in `Application`. I'm going to leave that detail out, but the declaration might be `Dictionary<char, int>`. Then you'd need a `chars` array to list what characters you want to measure. It might be defined like this `char[] chars = new char[] { 'a', 'b', ... }`.

Again, both of those will need to be stored in `Application`.

Then to build the dictionary you might do something like this (in the `Global.asax` file):

```
var b = new Bitmap(500, 200);
var g = Graphics.FromImage(b);

for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
{
    var len = g.MeasureString(chars[i] as string, new Font("Arial", 12));
    dict.Add(chars[i], len);
}
```

Comment: +0: while showing method to measure character's dimensions this method is absolutely useless for ASP.Net case as using `Graphics` on server is potentially dangerous, but more importantly it have nothing to do with font a browser will pick to render characters.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I fully understand your position (and it's a good perspective on the problem), but it does address the OP's question yes?

Comment: No it will not (as you can't get size of font that browser will use on server, especially *before* page is rendered by browser), but OP probably does not care about such things - so this solution may be accepted by the OP.